# SendKeys - not able to send "@"

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys

I am trying to automate username and password entry for `Exceed` using VB scripts, but `Exceed` is not accepting `^(shift)` `~(cntrl)` keys to send.

Somehow i managed to use caps lock for capital letters by toggling on/off. But now the problem I am facing is not being able to send `@`. I tried the `chr()` function to send `@`, but to no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: Share your code. I tried and didn't faced any issues.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to improve the readability of your question. Please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!